# Using Php i want to know how to get a colour input from a user and set that colour to the background of the page

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I'm curious if I'm on the right track.

```
<?php
    $color = readline("Enter background: ");
    echo "<div style = 'background-colour:\'$color\' '";

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm really struggling with PHP :)

Comment: readline is for input on the command line interface, and if you were working there, you would probably not really have a "page" to begin with. You tagged this with `forms` already, so I am assuming you want to do this via a form on the page, that the user can submit the color value with? Then you should go and find yourself a tutorial that explains the basics of processing form submissions in PHP first of all now - these are _basics_, and we are not here to teach those.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So here we have to separate the problem into 3 parts.

1 -> Get the user input, which should be either HEX, RGB, RGBA wtv...

2 -> Get that value onto a variable so that you can later on dynamically assign it to your HTML tag (body I suppose) and set its background color to the value of that variable.

3 -> Assign the value of the variable to your html tag.

After doing some research, I found this line.

Which mixes, my logic in fewer steps haha, but the logic remains the same.

```
<?php echo '<input type="hidden" maxlength=100 name="value" id="val" value="'.$myobj->foo.'">';
```

You just need to change the  to  and it should work.

Lmk how that goes.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand that man I'm sorry is there anyway you can dumb it down a little bit

Comment: Yes, of course. So, you want your user to choose a color right? That color must be either hex (#ffffff which stands for white) or rgb/rgba. You want to grab the users input and pass that down to the color: in css right? You can't pass that variable value to the css file (as far as I know), but you can define a variable ($color for example) to be equal to the users input. After that, you can pass that value directly to the <body> tag, like this.
 ```<?php echo '<body style="background-color: $color;" />';``` 
Idk if this is the right way to pass the variable though.

Comment: This way you can pass the value of the variable directly to the body and to its background-color property. Let me know if that made sense